# 16.04 - Gnome Software will not open. Flashes icon in launcher and then closes

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. When first installed I had ubuntu-software as my software center and when opening the application the Software Center icon would display in the launcher for a few seconds and then disappear without having ever shown the app.

I've purged and reinstalled ubuntu-software to no avail. I've now purged ubuntu-software and installed gnome-software and have the same results.

I am reading all over the web (in my effort to resolve this) that both appear to be plagued with bugs.

What are my next steps to take in troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Ubuntu 16.04, So i install Centro de software de Ubuntu v 15.12 and it work.

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

and then

```
software-center
```

finally I get the icon at side. That solves the problem for now.

Comment: I performed a fresh install of 16.04 after the latest LTS release. It was working and then after I restored my deja-dup backup it when loopy again.